# Superscript in yaml and haml

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, haml

Currently I have the key

```
registered_html: "<sup>®</sup>"
```

and I try to interpret it as `t("registered_html").html_safe` in the haml file but instead of the symbol being superscripted it just returns the the text directly like `"<sup>®</sup>"`. You can see in the picture below. How can I change this so it returns the superscripted symbol instead of `"<sup>®</sup>"`?

[image: rails console running the haml]

Answer (score 0):

[Just use it directly](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations), without the `html_safe` method

```
= t('registered_html')
```